# iOS - Implementation of MVC-Pattern without Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller

I'm creating a little MVC-sample-project as an iPhone-application in XCode, which is built completely with code and therefore doesn't use Interface Builder. First I'd like to show you the code I have so far.

### Controller

The controller instantiates the model and the view and also contains a function which demonstrates the independency between model and view:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainView.h"
#import "ProjectModel.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    ProjectModel *model;
    MainView *myMainView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    model = [[ProjectModel alloc] init];

    myMainView = [[MainView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 468)];
    [self.view addSubview:myMainView];

    //test function to illustrate that view and model are independent
    [self calculate];

}

- (void)calculate
{    
    int result = [model operationWithNumber:3 andAnotherNumber:5];
    [myMainView showResult:result];
}

@end
```

### Model

The class ProjectModel is responsible for the model of the project and is in this example for the sake of simplicity only responsible for summing up two numbers:

**ProjectModel.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ProjectModel : NSObject

-(int)operationWithNumber:(int)number1 andAnotherNumber:(int)number2;

@end
```

**ProjectModel.m**

```
#import "ProjectModel.h"

@implementation ProjectModel

-(int)operationWithNumber:(int)number1 andAnotherNumber:(int)number2
{
    return (number1 + number2);
}

@end
```

### View

The view-class creates all the elements of the view and contains a function which displays the result of a calculation in a label. 
**MainView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainView : UIView
{
    UILabel *lblResult;
}

- (void)showResult:(int)result;

@end
```

**MainView.m**

```
#import "MainView.h"

@implementation MainView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {        
        UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 50)];
        lblTitle.text = @"This is my View";
        [self addSubview:lblTitle];

        lblResult = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, 50)];
        lblResult.text = @"Result will be displayed here.";
        [self addSubview:lblResult];   
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)showResult:(int)result
{
    lblResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Resultat: %d", result];
}

@end
```

### My Question:

I hope you understood the code so far. Based on the code above, I'd like to implement a button in the view-class which should calculate and display two numbers when the users clicks this button. Thus when the user clicks the button, the calculate-function in the ViewController should be called. I created a button with the following code in MainView.m:

```
UIButton *btnCalculate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btnCalculate setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 90, 280, 50)];
[btnCalculate setTitle:@"Calculate" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnCalculate addTarget:self action:@selector(calculate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:btnCalculate];
```

The problem is this line in the code above:

```
[btnCalculate addTarget:self action:@selector(calculate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

how can I add a function from the controller as the action of the button. I know that the target should not be self, since the function should be called in the ViewController, but I have no idea how I could do that. Could anyone help me and tell me how I can solve this problem?

The only solution that I can see right now is that the complete GUI is created in the ViewController directly. But I don't think that this is a nice solution, since the main purpose of MVC is to avoid the mix of controller and view code in the same class.

Also I'm wondering whether this code generally conforms to the MVC-pattern propagated by Apple, since I'm pretty new to this design-pattern. I'd really appreciate a short feedback for this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the target in the view class. For MVC, the view should not explicitly know about the controller. The view class should have a public property to expose the button and then the controller can update the button to add the target.

Other than that it looks like you understand the point of MVC.

This line does confuse a bit `[self.view addSubview:view];` as it appears to be trying to add the view as a subview of itself...

Comment: this line sounds indeed a little bit strange. view is an instance of MainView and is added to the the view of ViewController, so it gets actually displayed. Maybe I should have called it myMainView or something like that. I will change that in my opening post.

Your solution sounds interesting, I will try that.

Comment: Yes, call the view something different as view controllers already have `view` property.

Comment: I implemented your solution by making the button in MainView public and adding this statement in ViewController:
    [myMainView.btnCalculate addTarget:self action:@selector(calculate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
It works and looks pretty nice. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The MVC pattern is a nice thing, but I don't think it is necessary for a program like yours to have that degree of separation. Also the button can be in the view class since it is a part of that pattern along with calculate function.

Comment: Yeah, for this kind of project the MVC pattern is not necessary. This project is just to illustrate my thoughts and ideas to the community in an easy and understandable way. Until now I coded everything (controller, model and view) in the ViewController, resulting in applications where I have thounsands lines of code  in this one and only file, which gets very confusing. That's the reason why I want to learn this design-pattern.

Comment: Not sure exactly if there is a precision way to really separate everything, I believe there probably is. Definitely you are correct in that many programs tend of have really chunky view controllers, in fact  some of the apple samples do as well its not just us.